# Marie Skłodowska-Curie Actions scholarship reserve list

Tags: funding, marie-curie

I applied for the Marie Curie Global Fellowship, and I was placed in the reserve list. Does anyone have experience of people placed in the reserve list who eventually got funded?

Comment: So, what happened? When I applied to  Marie Skłodowska-Curie actions (Individual Fellowships (IF), Call: H2020-MSCA-IF-2014), I obtained a Total score of 83.60% (the threshold: 70.0/100.00), but I don't even think there is a "reserve list" for that grant.

Comment: there is a reserve list, because I was officially told so. As far I knowit is not for people who reached the minimum threshold but for those who were very close to get funded. In my case the threshold to get the scholarship was 93.0/100. I scored 92.4. 

I asked info to MC national delegates. If someone renounces to the MSCA I could get it. But it is really hard that this is going to happen.